# how to load multiple trained weights in gluoncv?

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, mxnet, gluon

I have trained the `resnet50_v1b_voc` for two different objects and created the `params` file from the training. While the params files are working absolutely fine when I am doing prediction by loading only one throughout but getting issue in results if I load both of them together.

```
from gluoncv import model_zoo, data, utils
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

net = model_zoo.get_model('faster_rcnn_resnet50_v1b_voc', pretrained=True, ctx=mx.gpu())

net.load_parameters('/home/ubuntu/abc/faster_rcnn_resnet50_v1b_voc_best.params', ctx=mx.gpu())
net.load_parameters('/home/ubuntu/xyz/faster_rcnn_resnet50_v1b_voc_best.params', ctx=mx.gpu())

net.reset_class(['abc'], reuse_weights={'abc': 'abc'})
class_IDs, scores, bounding_boxs = net(x)
# This works fine if I predict the abc object

# But when I do this the confidence score is too low for the xyz object
# Individually if I perform this task with xyz params the results are perfect
net.reset_class(['xyz'], reuse_weights={'xyz': 'xyz'})
class_IDs, scores, bounding_boxs = net(x)
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: The code uses mx.gpu(), is this wrongly tagged intel-mxnet?

Comment: @ArunJose_Intel thanks for pointing out, I have removed the tag.

Answer (score 0):

The probable  cause of the issue is the reset_class():

**reset_class(classes, reuse_weights=None):** *Resets class categories and class predictors.*

The pre-trained model supports many classes in the training dataset.

After call net.reset_class(['abc'],…), the net output will be changed to only support one class: ‘abc’.
So, it would  perform worse when predicting on ‘xyz’.

Comment: so resetting the class should include both the classes of the parameters?